# Android SSL CN check for each request

Tags: android, ssl, webview, webkit

I need to intercept all requests from my `WebView` to check CN in SSL certificate. 
As far as I understand it's possible if
1. Write my own browser with custom trust manager
2. Use javascript bridge for all requests form the `WebView` and use the same `SSLSocketFactory` with custom trust manager.

Does anybody know other ways of doing that? Seems like extending webkit is the only good idea.

Thanks.

Comment: So basically you want to use SSL in android application with your Trust manager, right?

Comment: Yes, but on the webview I want to use normal javascript ajax function and for each SSL request I will need to check CN in my custom trustmanager